# UML-model class affectation

Tags: uml, class-diagram

[image]

I am trying to model with UML this problem I have, that is a specific exchanger structure.

I have the central class, *Matrix*, that has several circuits flowing through it, class *Circuit*. This matrix is a stack of passages (class *Passage*), in which circulates one or more circuits. One circuit can also flow several passages.

Let's say passages objects are named "`A`", "`B`" and "`C`", matrix can look like : `ABCCABA...`

I would use a reference, like an array of pointers

How do I model that stacking pattern in UML?

Then, I would like to say that `A` contains 2 circuits objects "`1`" and "`2`", `B` contains "`2`" and `C` contains "`3`".

Help me finding out how to do these

Comment: It may be a language problem, but classes do not flow and you can not stack them. Is it that you want to know how to model a class that represents a matrix? And another to model a stack?

Comment: Oh I see, maybe there's a mix-up in the use of "flow" and "stack". I do not really want to _stack_ or make _flow_ the classes itself, but the objects. And most importantly, I would like to understand what association types I'll have to use to make this structure work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question still is in a form that it allows (too) many answers, but I'll try this way.

- For each of the steps below involve the appropriate stakeholders to take part in the design.
- Make up your mind what you actually want to do. What is the purpose of the matrix/stack (your question does not provide background).

  - A good way is to create use cases to describe the goals of your system
- Provided you know what those system goals are create a domain using a class diagram. The above class diagram looks okay but without context I can't tell if it's right or wrong.
- Once you got that structural model you can start designing functionality. The best approach is this:

  - Create a collaboration for each of your use cases (also known as use case realizations; they have a realization towards the use case).
  - Inside each collaboration create sequence diagrams and place instances of those classes on it which are supposed to take part in this specific use case
  - Now start thinking how these instances need to communicate to perform the desired task
  - Draw a message to show the communication and create a method in the according class (some tools support this in one step)
  - Review communication and domain model

Roughly these are the major design steps. As you see I did not provide a specific answer to the problem you probably has in mind. Simply because it's not specific enough.

Give a person a fish and it will have a meal for a day. Teach it to fish and it has a meal for the rest of its life.

Comment: I've been looking for some sort of guidelines for some time now, I you just gave it to me. Thanks. I guess I'll think about it, and if it remains unclear, I'll come back for help if it's ok. Thanks !

Comment: No problem. You might vote-up if it helped :-) UML is a language. And you can only learn by practicing it. Just travel to UMLand where everyone speaks UML so you're forced to learn - or starve ;-) You're welcome to ask further question if you got stuck once again.

Comment: I know UML quite well, and if I didn't have other knowledge, I would STILL starve.  :)

Comment: @ThomasKilian: I've always recommended an activity diagram (where you have "collaboration") for each use case, with sequence diagrams for individual scenarios in the use case.

Comment: @BobRodes: The AD goes into the UC to describe what's going on. You can use AD alternatively to SD where appropriate (there's a 1:1 relation). AD are better in "structural overview" while SD are in "timely".

Comment: @ThomasKilian: I'm not sure I entirely agree that there's a 1:1 relation between AD and SD.  Maybe I'm missing your point?  I don't see an easy way to model parallel threads of behavior in a SD in the way that forks and joins do so well in an AD.  I see the SD as a bit lower level than the AD, too; it's hard to model the flow of interaction between two objects at the method call level in an AD.

Comment: Well, the fact that there is a 1:1 relation does not mean that the conversion is easy. Also the fact that you "can" do it must not mean you "must" do it. The focus of both is different as I stated. So you should use either where you think the focus is most needed. We might start a discussion on LinkedIn https://www.linkedin.com/groups?mostRecent=&gid=143183&trk=my_groups-tile-flipgrp

Answer (score 0):

The concrete structure of instances relations is to be shown in the [Object Diagram](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/VPGallery/diagrams/Object.html).

But it is not so powerful and universal as class diagram. So, very probably, you'll have to invent a diagram of your own.

Look also at [Composite Structure diagram](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/VPGallery/diagrams/CompositeStructureDiagram.html)